# node.js serialize/deserialize custom objects to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, serialization, ecmascript-6

I have the following architecture:

```
class Base {
  constructor(initObj) { /* some init */}
  // some methods
}

class Foo extends Base {
  constructor(initObj) { super(initObj); }
  // some methods
}

class Bar extends Base {
  constructor(initObj) { super(initObj); }
  // some methods
}
```

How can I serialize/deserialize an Array of `Base` into mongodb ?

For the moment, I save an attribute `type` on each object to know if its a `Foo` or a `Bar` and my Foo and Bar's constructor looks like that:

```
constructor(initObj) {
  super(initObj);
  if (initObj.fromMongo) this.restore(initObj)
  else this.initialize(initObj)
  this.type = 'bar'; // or baz according to the object
}
```

because as you can imagine, the creation from a saved object and from new data is not the same.

Does someone knows a less tricky way to realize these operations ?

Comment: Do you use mongoose?

Comment: no, I only use the mongodb driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mongoose these things are done easily. But as far as you don't, I can suggest you such flow:

- you have collection base in mongo, with field type, that specifies foo or bar instance
- implement deserialize method in base
- you implement serialize method in each child class
- you use your methods, when having array of base objects

I would modify base class:

```
class Base {
  constructor(initObj) { /* some init */}

  serialize(model) {
    throw new Error('not implemented')
  }

  deserialize(mongoModel) {
    // very rude, just to catch the point
    // most probably, you'll have to map object before creating new instance
    if (mongoModel.type === 'Foo') return new Foo(mongoModel);
    else return new Bar(mongoModel);
  }
}
```

I'll write approximate implementation of these methods:

```
class Foo extends Base {
  constructor(initObj) { super(initObj); }

  serialize(model) {
    // again very rude, it dependes on your logic
    return JSON.stringify(model);
  }
}
```

And then, assuming you have array of Base objects you can easily map them:

```
const mongoBaseModels = baseObjects.map(el => el.serialize(el))
```